# Video Training Site built with Expression Engine

Tags: ee2, ee, video

I'm looking to build a billing video training site with Expression Engine so I'm wondering if anyone in this community has built one and what add-ons you recommend.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For your addons inventory, you might consider

- Stash
- Channel Videos
- Channel Images
- Matrix
- Low Search
- Low Variables
- Visitor
- CartThrob2

to build the site you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks Mohammad! Do you have examples of live sites?